# HTML 5 audio tag issues (no sound) with phonegap on android 4.x

Tags: html, cordova

**Platform**: Android version 4.x

**Issue**: HTML 5 Audio Tag

**Compiled**:  Framework Phonegap

I have been trying to play a simple sound with HTML 5, i cant get it to work.

I read that there is a general "not supporting" thing going on with Android, but as i understand it, version 4.x supports HTML 5 Audio tag.

**Config.xml**
I did enable some of the features in it eg.  File access, device access and so, i even tried to include all features.  Just to let u guys know.

**HTML**
This is what i am working with atm, i figured that maybe i should go back to directly try and get a sound out, then make the costum controls with JQ.

```
<audio controls="true">
    <source src="media/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="media/sound.ogg"  type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="media/sound.wav"  type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
```

**Conclusion**
So far i havent hear any sounds, i tried to trigger it different ways like:

```
var Newsound = new Audio("sound.ogg");
Newsound.play();
```

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I want to add that i have been looking at around 20 different examples, most where from stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally need a piece of JavaScript to get this working. Try the following:

```
<audio id="a" controls="true">...

var audio = document.getElementById('a');
audio.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { audio.play(); }, false);
```

When a user touches the audio element the sound should now play.

Comment: Man thats a great idea, let me try it, ill let you know :-)

Comment: I am going to accept your answer even though it dident solve my problem 100%.  You did help me, and i have to close this question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Ian Devlin

I tried it, and i dident get a sound so far.

New updated exmaple:

**HTML Head Section**

```
<script>
  var audio = document.getElementById('myplayer');
  audio.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { audio.play(); }, false);
</script>
```

**HTML Body Section**

```
<body>
  <audio controls="true" id="myplayer">
    <source src="media/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="media/1.ogg"  type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="media/1.wav"  type="audio/wav">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
  </audio>  
</body>
```

Comment: Try removing the type attribute from the mp3 source, so it's just <source src="media/1.mp3">

Comment: Tried that too, still no sound :-I

Comment: Have you confirmed that the sound files are actually valid and that they work?

Comment: My MP3 file works in normal webbrowsers through the Audio tag.

Comment: however, i am not sure which file that is best to test with on an android OS.  Mp3, OGG or Wav. :)

Comment: MP3 should work fine. Do you have an online example of this particular piece of code that I could look at?

Comment: I can upload it to a subdomain sure as a zip file, would that be ok?

Comment: www.ao-horizon.org/pg/app.zip   here u go, i just created a folder.

Comment: Ok well I just knocked up this and tested it on my Android (4.1.2) phone and it worked fine: http://iandevlin.com/html5/audio/android/. I also tested it on an Android 4.0.3 emulator and it also worked just fine.

Comment: Yes it works fine when the sound files are online.  But if put the mp3/ogg files in a folder in my app, which i compile with the phonegap framework, it wont work.  So i need to have my files locally in my app, compiled through phonegap.

Comment: Aaaahhhhh I see. That's different. This should push you on the right path: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/41Hdim9k9EE

Comment: It might be that im a tad to fast on this question.  But if i compile my app through phonegap, and in that app im compiling there is a folder called "media".  In the "media" folder which is in my zip file that i uploaded to phonegap, shall i access that through the ""file:///home/user/media/sound.mp3" <-- like this?

Comment: I Mean.. i dont know the path to my sound files.  The sound files it not on the phone, they should come with the app.

Comment: in my HTML world the path would be "media/sound.mp3".  I hope that you understand what im refering to here :-)

Comment: I do know what you mean, but I don't know the answer. You'll have to google how to find the upload path, this isn't a specific HTML5 audio issue.

Comment: This is a specefic HTML 5 audio issue.  I have a folder on my desktop that holds my entire app project.  In that folder is a index.html, config.xml ect.. Buuutt... there is also a folder called "media", which i am refering to in my original example, this is what im interested in reaching.  I want to play sound files from that folder :-)

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing same issue in Android >= 4.2, in Android from 2.2 to 4.0 works fine, don't have a 4.1 Android at hand to see if it works, this is my code:

```
<audio autoplay loop autobuffer>
    <source src="http://buecrplb01.cienradios.com.ar/Mitre790.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Note on loop attribute: I've found some streams played for 1 second and stopped, after adding loop attr they played continuously.